# How do I return the data using ImportXML into separate columns Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I'm using ImportXML in a Google Spreadsheet to input the population demographics from the website https://www.socialexplorer.com/profiles/essential-report/zcta5-48105.html. I'd like to extract the population, square miles, and people per square mile into a three-column display of the results.

Currently, I'm doing this by limiting to only these three rows:

`=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTXML("https://www.socialexplorer.com/profiles/essential-report/zcta5-48105.html", "//div[contains(@class,'c-num')]")),"select * limit 4",-1)`

But the output comes out like

```
N population
N square miles
N people per square mile
```

and I want it to look like

```
Population   Square Miles     People Per Square Mile
N               N                      N
```

Is there a way for me to create this display?

Ideally, I would be able to export the fields Median Age, Bachelor's Degree or Higher, Per Capita Income, etc. as well.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It looks that you question rather than being about [tag:web-scraping] (getting data from a website) is about data transformation (changing the shape of data), but the last statement makes the question "to require more focus". Please [edit] the question to focus on a specific issue. Ideally you should include a brief description of your search efforts to find helpful content from this site related to the issue that you want to solve.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with this:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTXML("https://www.socialexplorer.com/profiles/essential-report/zcta5-48105.html", "//div[contains(@class,'c-num')]")),"select Col2,Col1 limit 4",-1))
```

Comment: Is there a way I could do this to exclude the header "Population Density", etc. everytime?

Comment: So as to show the values as such:   N               N                      N

Comment: You can select a specific row with INDEX: =INDEX(THE_FORMULA,2)

Comment: What does the 2 represent? How would I be able to output multiple different rows?

Comment: 2 is the number of the row being exported. Your data does not include more rows, I suggest you mark this question as answered and open a new one with a specific case. With INDEX you can't get more rows, but you'll probably manage it with other functions